# Combinatorics for exterior power for arbitrary Specht module

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, young-tableaux

The exterior powers of the standard representation are easily seen to be the representations whose Young diagrams have only boxes in the first row or first column. But, what if I start with an arbitrary Specht module (i.e arbitrary Young diagram)? And then you take exterior powers of that Young diagram (i.e action on tensor products modulo the anticommuting relation). Is there a combinatorial interpretation in terms of young diagrams for how this exterior power decomposes?